# Removing characters from multiple rows and multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset that contains 150k rows and 40 columns. The dataset consists of characters, strings as well as integers. I want to remove particular cells which contains a specific keyword/phrase that I want to remove.
For example,
If the initial dataset looks like

```
            A            B
 1)             1 | My name is Sam.
 2)         Hello | 2
 3)   Who are you | The water is green.
```

I want to remove the cell that contains the keyword "is". So that the final dataset will look like:-

```
            A            B
 1)             1 | NA
 2)         Hello | 2
 3)   Who are you | NA
```

The keyword can be in any format like a combination of strings or numbers or both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using grepl you can replace the entries in a single column that contain the word "is" with NA as Akrun has shown. To make that occur over all columns, you can convert the dataframe to a vector first, subbing out the strings with "is", and then rebuilding the dataframe.

```
k <- 150
n <- 1000 * k
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c("Hi, my name is Khal Drogo", "Hello Khal Drogo", 1, 2), replace = T, size = n), ncol = k))

dfvec <- as.vector(unlist(df1))
dfvec[grepl("\\bis\\b", dfvec)] <- NA
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(dfvec, ncol = k))
head(df1[,1:5])
```

Which gives this:

```
> head(df1[,1:5])
                X1               X2               X3               X4               X5
1 Hello Khal Drogo             <NA>                1                2                1
2 Hello Khal Drogo                2             <NA>                1 Hello Khal Drogo
3 Hello Khal Drogo Hello Khal Drogo                1                1             <NA>
4             <NA>                1 Hello Khal Drogo                2                2
5                2 Hello Khal Drogo             <NA>                2                1
6                2 Hello Khal Drogo Hello Khal Drogo Hello Khal Drogo                2
```

Answer (score 2):

We can assign it to `NA` by creating a logical index with `grep`

```
df1$B[grepl("\\bis\\b", df1$B)] <- NA
```

If `is` can be also a substring, then remove the word boundary

```
df1$B[grepl("is", df1$B)] <- NA
```

---

It is also possible that the OP wants to assign all non-numeric elements to NA. In that case, just converting the column to `numeric` (assuming it is `character` class)

```
df1$B <- as.numeric(df1$B)
```

#### Update

If there are multiple columns, then we can use `lapply`

```
colsofInterest <- 2:ncol(df1)
df1[colsofInterest] <- lapply(df1[colsofInterest],
         function(x) replace(x, grepl("\\bis\\b", x), NA))
```

---

Or this can be also done with `tidyverse`

```
library(tdivyerse)
df1 %>%
     mutate_at(vars(colsofInterest), funs(replace(., str_detect(., "\\bis\\b"), NA)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will try it out

Comment: Thanks for the updated code @akrun . Both methods work perfectly and give the correct output. Never thought getting this result would be so simple. Hope I will be able to help you in the future! :)